# Problema con Punteros

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio sencillo en donde tengo que ingresar dos enteros y calcular distintas operaciones mediante funciones.

La cuestion es que me pide estos dos prototipos de funciones:

```
int * multi (int, int);
int * resta (int, int);
```

Tengo varias dudas:

1. ¿En qué beneficia que la funcion retorne un puntero y no una variable de tipo int con el resultado?
2. No entiendo muy bien como funciona el sistema de retornar punteros mediante funciones.

Dejo el codigo que hice yo que obviamente no me funciona en esas dos funciones.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void suma (int, int, int *);
void divi (int, int, int*);
int * multi (int, int);
int * resta (int, int);



int main()
{
int num1,num2,op,results,resultd;
int *resultm;
int *resultr;


printf("Ingrese el primer numero:  ");
scanf ("%d",&num1);   
printf("Ingrese el segundo numero:  ");
scanf ("%d",&num2); 

printf("Elija una de las siguientes opciones: \n");
printf (" 1-Suma \n 2-Division \n 3-Multiplicacion \n 4-Resta \n 0-Salir \n");
scanf("%d",&op);

while (op>0&&op<=4)
 { switch (op)
         { case 1: suma (num1,num2,&results);
                   printf("El resultado es: %d \n", results);
                   break;
           case 2: divi (num1,num2,&resultd);
                   printf("El resultado es: %d \n", resultd);
                   break;
           case 3: resultm= multi(num1,num2);
                   printf("El resultado es: %d \n", resultm);
                   break;
           case 4: resultr=resta(num1,num2);
                   printf("El resultado es: %d \n", resultr);
                   break; }
 printf("Elija una de las siguientes opciones: \n");
 printf (" 1-Suma \n 2-Division \n 3-Multiplicacion \n 4-Resta \n 0-Salir \n");
 scanf("%d",&op); }

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

void suma (int a,int b,int *punts)
 {  
  *punts=a+b; }

 void divi (int a,int b,int *puntd)
  {
   *puntd=a/b; }

 int * multi (int a,int b)
  {
  int *r;


r=(a*b);
return r; }

int * resta (int a,int b)
 {
  int *rr;

rr=(a-b);
return rr; }
```

Comment: He añadido un par de cosas. Espero que te sirvan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, lo que está mal en `multi( )`, siendo aplicable a `resta( )`:

```
int * multi (int a, int b ) {
  int *r;

  r = ( a * b );

  return r;
}
```

Al hacer `r = ( a * b )`, estas asignando **a un puntero** el resultado de una multiplicación. Aunque *fuerces* al compilador a aceptarlo, el resultado sera, cuando menos, *indefinido*; estas haciendo que el **puntero** *apunte* a una dirección arbitraria, que creo que no es lo que pretendes.

Nota la diferencia entre asignar **a un puntero** o **al dato apuntado**; no es lo mismo. En otras partes de tu código, como `*punts = a + b` lo haces bien, asignas el valor **al dato apuntado**. El *asterisco* (*) delante de la variable *marca la diferencia*. Sin el, asignas *al puntero*. Con el, asignas *al dato apuntado*.

Ventajas de hacerlo asi: en tu código, absolutamente ninguna. En otros casos, solo depende de tu imaginación. Piensa, por ejemplo, en la función `malloc( )`, que asigna bloques de memória. ¿ Como lo harías sin devolver un puntero ? (vale, es una pregunta trampa. Se podría hacer con *punteros a punteros* ** ). Un uso **muy común** es en funciones que crean e inicializan `struct` u otros TAD (Tipo Abstracto de Dato), y devuelven punteros a los datos creados.

Por lo que deduzco del código, el objetivo del ejercicio es que *reutilices* una misma variable `resultado` para **todas las operaciones**, y practiques con las posibles formas de usarla mediante punteros: pasando un puntero como argumento, o bien devolviendo un puntero como resultado.

Mi versión del mismo ejercicio. Como *ejercicio* :-p , busca mis cambios e intenta comprenderlos según lo dicho aquí; veo en tu código que ya usas todo lo necesario (excepto el `do`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int results; // FUERA de main, para que sea accesible por todas las funciones.

void suma( int, int, int * );
void divi( int, int, int * );
int *multi( int, int ); 
int *resta( int, int );

int main( ) {
  int num1, num2, op;

  printf( "Ingrese el primer numero:  " );
  scanf( "%d", &num1 );

  printf( "Ingrese el segundo numero:  " );
  scanf( "%d", &num2 ); 

  do {
    printf( "Elija una de las siguientes opciones: \n" );
    printf( " 1-Suma \n 2-Division \n 3-Multiplicacion \n 4-Resta \n 0-Salir \n" );
    scanf( "%d", &op );

    switch( op ) {
    case 1:
      suma( num1, num2, &results );
      printf( "El resultado es: %d \n", results );
      break;

    case 2:
      divi( num1, num2, &results );
      printf( "El resultado es: %d \n", results );
      break;

    case 3:
      printf("El resultado es: %d \n", *multi( num1, num2 ) );
      break;

    case 4:
      printf("El resultado es: %d \n", *resta( num1, num2 ) );
      break;
    }
  } while( op );

  system( "PAUSE" );
  return 0;
}

void suma( int a, int b, int *punts ) {  
  *punts = a + b;
}

void divi( int a, int b, int *puntd ) {
  *puntd = a / b;
}

int *multi( int a, int b ) {
  results = a * b;
  return &results;
}

int *resta( int a, int b ) {
  results = a - b;
  return &results;
}
```

Pd.: lo se, soy *muy quisquilloso* con el formato del código xD.

**EDITO**

El trabajo con punteros es *igual* que el trabajo con datos *normales*. Solo podemos asignar un valor a una variable del tipo correcto. Lo principal es recordar que *puntero a int* **es un tipo** en si mismo:

```
int a = 10; // tipo de a -> int
int *b = &a; // tipo de b -> puntero a int
char *str = "hola, mundo !!"; // tipo de str -> puntero a caracter

int c = a; // mismo tipo

int d = b; // NO. TIPOS DISTINTOS.

int *z = b; // mismo tipo

char ch1 = str; // NO. TIPOS DISTINTOS.

char ch2 = *str; // mismo tipo
```

Añado un pequeño ejemplo; una función `swapInt( )` que *intercambia* el valor de 2 `int` mediante punteros; devuelve `0` si los datos *son iguales*, `1` si *son distintos*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int swapInt( int *, int * );

int main( void ) {
  int dato1 = 10, dato2 = 20;
  int inter;

  printf( "dato1 = %d, dato2 = %d\n", dato1, dato2 );

  inter = swapInt( &dato1, &dato2 );

  printf( "dato1 = %d, dato2 = %d, se intercambiaron: %d\n", dato1, dato2, inter );

  return 0;
}

void swapInt( int *a, int *b ) {
  int tmp;

  // Comparamos los punteros.
  if( a == b )
    return 0;

  // Comparamos los valores de los datos apuntados.
  if( *a == *b )
    return 0;

  tmp = *a; // tmp == 10.
  a = *b;   // a == 20.
  *b = tmp; // b == 10.

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Muchisias gracias!!! Me re sirvio lo que me acabas de explicar! :D de a poco voy aprendiendo y entendiedo mas!!

Comment: Una pregunta, si el retorno de la funcion "resta" o "multi" se lo quiero asignar a un puntero del programa principal en vez de mostrar el resultado directamente desde Printf, como tengo que hacer?? discula las molestias. Gracias  @Trauma

Answer (score 2):

> ¿En que beneficia que la funcion retorne un puntero y no una variable de tipo int con el resultado?

En un programa final no te beneficia en nada. Usar las variables por valor es mucho más sencillo y rápido que usarlas vía puntero. Además, con los punteros suele entrar en juego la memoria dinámica y ésta suele ser una fuente de problemas bastante importante.

Sin embargo no hay que olvidar que ahora mismo estás aprendiendo y durante el aprendizaje tienes que interiorizar cómo funciona el lenguaje y eso incluye el uso de punteros y la gestión de memoria dinámica y esa es precisamente la finalidad de estos ejercicios.

> No entiendo muy bien como funciona el sistema de retornar punteros mediante funciones

Los punteros no dejan de ser variables. Un puntero no es más que, en vez de almacenar un valor directo hace lo propio con direcciones de memoria... de hecho podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
int* ptr;
ptr = 5;
printf("%d",ptr); // 5
```

No es desde luego ni el uso más limpio ni el más recomendable para el caso de punteros pero sirve para demostrar que no dejan de ser variables al uso.

Dado que los punteros almacenan direcciones de memoria en vez de valores o resultados su principal utilidad es que permiten compartir información entre diferentes procesos. Como vemos en el siguiente ejemplo esto no es posible sin punteros:

```
void Incrementa(int var)
{ var++; }

void Decrementa(int var)
{ var--; }

void IncrementaPtr(int* var)
{ *var++; }

void DecrementaPtr(int* var)
{ *var--; }

int main()
{
  int variable = 0;
  Incrementa(variable);
  Incrementa(variable);
  printf("%d\n",variable); // 0

  Decrementa(variable);
  printf("%d\n",variable); // 0

  IncrementaPtr(&variable);
  IncrementaPtr(&variable);
  printf("%d\n",variable); // 2

  DecrementaPtr(&variable);
  printf("%d\n",variable); // 1
}
```

Como se puede ver, las funciones que no usan punteros no permiten modificar el valor almacenado en la variable, mientras que las que sí usan puntero son capaces de modificar el valor de la variable ubicada en la función `main()`.

Otra ventaja de los punteros es que son capaces de almacenar listas de elementos:

```
int lista[100];
```

La variable anterior es, realmente, un puntero. Vale que, por cómo está declarada, tiene ciertas limitaciones con respecto a los punteros normales, pero no deja de ser un puntero. Lo que está sucediendo en la línea anterior es que el sistema reserva 100 posiciones consecutivas de tipo `int` y hace que el puntero `lista` apunte a la primera de ellas. Así, para acceder a cualquier elemento de la lista nos basta con aplicar un desplazamiento deterimnado. Así, las siguientes operaciones son equivalentes:

```
int valor;

valor = lista[5]; // Acceso por índice

valor = *(lista+5); // Aritmética de punteros

valor = *(5+lista); // Aritmética de punteros 

valor = 5[lista]; // Acceso por índice, funciona pero no te la recomiendo ;)
```

¿Por qué te cuento este coñazo?

Porque es necesario conocer las diferentes utilidades de los punteros antes de entender qué sucede al retornar un puntero.

Si tu tienes una variable y la devuelves con un return... ¿qué sucede? Que se copia dicho valor en la variable que capture el `return`:

```
int func()
{ return 5; }

int main()
{
  int var = func(); // var captura el return
  printf("%d",var);
}
```

Si ahora en vez de una variable devuelves un puntero, ¿Qué sucede? Que se copia la dirección de memoria:

```
int* func()
{ return 5; } // Aquí puede que aparezca un warning

int main()
{
  int* var = func();
  printf("%d",var);
}
```

Ahora bien, retornar punteros tiene ciertas limitaciones y complicaciones:

1. No se puede retornar un array de tamaño fijo:

   ```
   int* func()
   {
     int lista[100];
     return lista; // ERROR!!!!
   }
   ```
2. Hay que tener cuidado con variables desreferenciadas:

   ```
   int* func()
   {
     int valor = 10;
     return &valor;
   }

   int main()
   {
     int* var = func();
     printf("%d",*var); // Cuidado!!! la variable valor ya no existe!!!
   }
   ```
3. Hay que tener cuidado con las fugas de memoria (memoria dinámica que se crea y no se destruye)

   ```
   int* func()
   {
     int* ptr = (int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
     return ptr;
   }

   int main()
   {
     int* var = func();

     var = func(); // La primera reserva de memoria la has perdido!!!!
     free(var);
   }
   ```

> La cuestion es que me pide estos dos prototipos de funciones: int * multi (int, int); int * resta (int, int);

En este caso a mí me indica que te están pidiendo que trabajes con memoria dinámica:

```
int* multi(int a, int b)
{
  int* ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); // Reservamos espacio para un único elemento
  *ptr = a*b;
  return ptr;
}

int main()
{
  int* ptr = multi(3,4);
  printf("%d",*ptr);
  free(ptr);
}
```

Como bien dije al principio no es la forma más elegante ni la más recomendada de abordar este problema en una solución real... pero no hay que olvidar que ahora estás aprendiendo y esta es una fase más de dicho proceso.